# Back,Start,Stop,Help in Dialog Chain

Tags: botframework

Just wanted to know if it is possible to implement functionality like(back, start, restart, stop) in Dialog chain similar to what we get in FormFlow? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can do it by somethings like context.Done, context.Forward, context.Call, and so on and so on.

Comment: context.wait will "wait" for another message, done will resume your parent dialog etc : [more here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/de/db4/interface_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_internals_1_1_i_dialog_stack.html)

Comment: please  share example for back in dialog chain if user enters back then control will go to previous dialog in chain from current dialog

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above by @activ8, such functionality can be achieved by using the built-in methods to manipulate the Dialog Stack.

[Click here to see a list of the C# methods.](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/de/db4/interface_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_internals_1_1_i_dialog_stack.html)

[To see how to achieve the same effect with the NodeJS SDK, click here.](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/session/#dialog-stack)

**Code Example for NodeJS:**

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {
        session.beginDialog('/askName');
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.send('Hello %s!', results.response);
    }
]);
bot.dialog('/askName', [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.endDialogWithResult(results);
    }
]);
```